# Standardized residuals of a Tobit model in R 

Tags: r, residuals, tobit-regression

Does anybody know why it is not possible to compute standardized residuals when estimating a Tobit model?

Here is a short example of what I am talking about:

```
> require(AER)   # for tobit estimation commands
> require(MASS)  # for computing standardized residuals
> numberofdrugs <- rpois(84, 5)+1
> healthvalue <- rpois(84,5)
> tob <- tobit(healthvalue ~ numberofdrugs)
> residuals(tob) # works fine
> stdres(tob)    # doesn't work fine
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in assuming that `stdres()` will work for a tobit regression. The reason `resid()` works for `tob` is that the type of object returned by `tobit()` inherits from class "survreg":

```
R> class(tob)
[1] "tobit"   "survreg"
```

and there is a special `residuals()` method for objects of that class:

```
R> methods(residuals)
 [1] residuals.breakpointsfull* residuals.coxph*          
 [3] residuals.coxph.null*      residuals.coxph.penal*    
 [5] residuals.default          residuals.glm             
 [7] residuals.HoltWinters*     residuals.isoreg*         
 [9] residuals.lm               residuals.loglm*          
[11] residuals.nls*             residuals.smooth.spline*  
[13] residuals.survreg*         residuals.survreg.penal*  
[15] residuals.tukeyline*      

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

("survreg" is there as number 13.)

`stdres()` is (or at least appears to me to be) limited to the linear model case, and one could argue that a tobit model is not a linear regression. From `?stdres` we have:

```
Arguments:

  object: any object representing a linear model.
```

That this is the case is seen more clearly when one looks at `lmwork()`, the function that does the work in `stdres()`, which on the second line of the code for that function, `lm.influence()` is called, and that is where `stdres()` is failing (output from debugging `lmwork()` and calling `stdres(tob)`:

```
Browse[2]> n
debug: resid <- object$residuals
Browse[2]> 
debug: hat <- lm.influence(object, do.coef = FALSE)$hat
Browse[2]> 
Error in if (model$rank == 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I'm not familiar with survival models nor tobit regression. Read `?residuals.survreg` and see if that is doing the right thing regarding standardising the residuals (there is something in there about using sigma). otherwise you might have to cook this yourself or contact the author of the survival package for suggestions as to how to compute the standardised residuals that you want.